# Permissions directive with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I working on an SPA that works with a REST server on the backend.

My goal is to create an interface, that will be mutual to all of the roles.

for instance: 
On a product page, a guest can view the product and the comments, a registered user also has a text box where he can comment.
The administrator can edit both comments and the product it self, and everything is done within the same view at the SPA.

So in fact we have DOM element that should not be 'compiled' for some users, but should be 'compiled' for others.

What I am doing in order to control the access to my application, is resolving a factory that grantees that the use has the sufficient priviledges to access a certain page, this factory also populates the rootScope with his access level.

Then on the compile function of the xLimitAccess directive I check if the access level of the current user is sufficient to view the content within the directive and then remove it.

**Problem:** there is no way to access the $rootScope from the compile function(because it doesn't exist yet), and if I'll do it in the link function, it is already too late, and the element cannot be removed from the DOM

HTML code example:

```
<div class="product">...</div>

<div class="manageProduct" x-limit-access x-access-level="admin">...</div>

<div class="commnet" x-limit-access x-access-level="user, admin">...</div>

<div class="commnet" x-limit-access x-access-level="admin">...</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('home', []);
// var host = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.
    when('/', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html', 
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            resolve: {auth : 'authUser'} //this is a page only for logged in users
        }).
    when('/login', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html', 
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            resolve: {}
        }).
    when('/logout', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/logout.html',
            controller: 'logoutCtrl',
            resolve: {auth : 'authUser'} //this is a page only for logged in users

        }).
    when('/register', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            controller: 'registerController',
            resolve: {}
        }).
    when('/admin', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/admin/home.html',
            controller: 'registerController',
            resolve: {auth: 'authAdmin'}
        }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).
run(function($rootScope, $location, $http, authUser){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, rejection){
        if(rejection.status == 401)
            $location.path('/login');
    })

    $http.get('/users/me', {withCredentials: true}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $rootScope.roles = data.roles;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    });
});

app.factory('authUser', function($http){
        return $http.head('/users/me', {withCredentials: true});
});

app.directive('xLimitAccess', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: {
            xAccessLevel: '='
        }
        compile: function(element,$rootScope){//this is essentially the problem
            if(scope.xAccessLevel != $rootScope.roles)
                element.children().remove();
                elemnet.remove();
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Only looking at the specific problem, of not having `$rootScope` in your directive's compile function: you can inject it into your directive instead of into your compile function as follows: `app.directive('xLimitAccess', function ($rootScope) { }`. The compile function does not support injection—it [gets passed a set of values directly](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L869).

Comment: As far as I understand, the rootScope doesn't yet exist during the compile phase, so your solution won't help me much, correcr me if I am wrong.

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: It does exist in the compile phase. TIAS!

Comment: OK, So I've done some major restructuring in my code, and created a factory called authService, with an authUser method/function.

but now this service function cannot be resolved at the router, help :(